# IIS Configuration for Rest Service Client

Tags: asp.net, iis, restsharp

In Company where I work, we have an ASP.NET web application that is hosted on IIS server and binded already with CertificateA. This certificate is owned by the company.

There is another Company let say CompanyB that is providing some Rest API service based on paid subscription.
CompanyB provides subscribers with CertificateB and ask them to send CirtificateB along with the http request when invoking the Rest service.
We have subscribed and received a copy of the CertificateB.

We imported CertificateB on the server and uses Restsharp package from NuGet library to achieve the goal.
It works perfectly and get the proper response when I run the application from within Visual Studio.
However, when I publish it on IIS and run the application I am getting error says:

"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Provided that both IIS and visual studio installed on the same machine.

As I said the binding of our web application is already using CertificateA.

Is there any configuration on IIS need to be done regarding CertificateB.
Thank u

I wish we get rid of this error

Comment: That company really should have provided you all the details, as many developers have no idea that many differences exist https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 until they hit such an issue.

Comment: Or in short, you can attach the certificate in C#, as posts like https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1623 indicated. Otherwise, you need to learn where is the personal store of your application pool identity and configure the client certificate properly for that account. Ask your server/domain administrators to help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue resolved. All I have to do is to give the right permission to the application pool identity to be able to access the certificate.